# How to make a fixed layout into a fluid one from certain breakpoint?

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

I need to have my layout fixed until the window is more than 960px wide. After that, it should go fluid while maintaining the relations of the previous grid system. Is there a best practice to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's called media queries. and you can use it to write css for specific width, so by that turning your layout into a fluid one.

```
@media (min-width:400px) and (max-width: 950px) {
    /* your css for the fluid layout */
}
```

Here's a small guide to that http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries